# Accessing float property through DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a DOM element that in Firebug clearly shows a `float: left` property.
But when I process it in the DOM, `element.style.float` returns `undefined`.

Am I just overlooking something on my end (this is what I'm assuming right now) or is there a special way to address `float`? I would be baffled if there were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cssFloat`.

Source.
http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domcss

Comment: Holy camoley, and this after ten years of web development! I'm baffled. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

element.style.cssFloat (styleFloat in IE) uses a convention of the browsers to assign attributes as property names in the html engine. Sometimes they work, other times not.
keywords can't be property names in a script- class, for, float become className, htmlFor, cssFloat or styleFloat.

The dom syntax is:
**element.style.getPropertyValue('float'),** 
but that will only work for inline style assignments.

To get any stylesheet defined style you must look deeper:

**document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element,'').getPropertyValue('float');**

Note- this is for firefox, opera, chrome, safari. 
IE has its own methods for style look ups.